# CloudFront like reverse proxy instead Varnish

Tags: magento-1.9, cookie, varnish, proxy, cloudfront-cdn

I know that CloudFront is CDN, not reverse proxy, but if I understand correctly now is possible to use CloudFront to serve everything behind it.

I found few links, and seems like it is possible. For example:
http://www.zhudev.com/2018/10/19/use-aws-cloudfront-with-ec2-instance/
He set it, but I can't find any info if cookies will be problem and what problems can cause full page caching.
I found somewhere that cart can be problem for example, and also privileges in admin panel.

Does someone set like that?
Do you can me direct somewhere when I can read and understand how to set it up?

My plan is to set like:
Public ---> CloudFront -> ELB -> ASG